# Auto-creating a database schema with hibernate /derby

Tags: hibernate, jpa, derby

I am trying to create an in-memory derby database with hibernate, for testing.
I would like the schema and tables to be automatically created.
My persistence.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sanddb_test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.ibm.sand.index.tags.MyEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, when I'm trying to persist, I get the following exception saying that the schema does not exist:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
    at com.ibm.sand.index.tags.DbTaggingInfoPersistenceManager.storeTaggingInfo(DbTaggingInfoPersistenceManager.java:21)
    at com.ibm.sand.index.tags.DbTaggingInfoPersistenceManagerTest.test(DbTaggingInfoPersistenceManagerTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLModStatementNode.verifyTargetTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 55 more
```

I am using hibernate 4.2.3 and derby 10.8.2.2.
What should I do in order for the schema to be created automatically?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why the ADMIN schema was not created, but I found out that if I'm using the default schema: "APP", I can bypass this problem

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Hibernate cannot create a schema for you. At least not before tables are created. So you have to use an existing schema by setting javax.persistence.jdbc.user. I usually use Eclipselink and haven't had any problems there. But I'm betting there is a workaround for Hibernate's issue, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I set the catelog attribute of class tag as follows and got it to work:

```
<class .... catelog="APP" ...>
```

Comment: You might have missed the rest of your answer? Click too soon to post?

Comment: When you deal with XML, XHTML, HTML, or any other type of formatting that uses `<>`-style tags, it's very important you format it as code. Otherwise SO parses it as a part of the page rather than as something to display as plain text. You can format code by pre- and postfixing a block with three backticks (`), or a single if it's inline. For blocks, you can also indent by four spaces (which I did in this case). See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.